# Return First Part of HTML Class Name

Tags: jquery

I have a number of table rows that are each assigned several classes. And one of those classes will be *IndexN*, where *N* is a number from 0 to 5 or so.

What is the easiest way to get the value of *N* for a given row.

I know I can use `hasClass()` but that would require calling it for all possible values of *N*. I also assume I can simply get the value of the `class` attribute but this will include the other classes as well.

Is there a better way?

Comment: A better way would to use a `data-index="n"` attribute. It would save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Yes, but I have to work with the attributes in the HTML I'm using.

Comment: Why not use the rowIndex property? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp

Comment: you can use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: "index" methods don't make sense, I assume, because the elements could be out of order. `<br class="index424"><br class="index8">`...

Comment: Yes, it would be a brittle design indeed to make the results depend on the order classes appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('tr[class*=index]').each(function(){
  var cn = /\bindex(\d+)\b/.exec($(this).attr('class'));
  console.log(cn[1]);
});
```

console.log output is 1, 2, 3, 4

index[x] doesn't need to be listed first. It can be anywhere in the class string

Comment: Why `cn[1]`? What is in `cn[0]`?

Comment: cn[0] is "index1" or the whole matched string.   cn[1] is just the number 1 or the digit we matched in parenthesis (\d+). I thought he just wanted the digit.

Comment: I like this. The weakest part is that it wouldn't distinguish between "Index1" and "Windex1", but that seems unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: fixed it by adding \b or "word boundary" to the regex.

Comment: You might want to move the index value to the "id" attribute.  <tr id="index1" class="yadda yadda yadda"> or to a data attribute like <tr data-index="1" class="bloop beep bop">

Comment: @JonathanWood One possible downside is if your tr class is simply 'windex' (no 'indexN'). In that case, cn[1] will probably be undefined as the regex match would have failed.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Even with the word boundary flag to the regex? This won't match "windex".

Comment: @JonathanWood - Correct, but `tr[class*=index]` could give you a false positive. Just a note to double-check within your code. You can't assume that cn[1] will return a value.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, it's not an issue. That is not part of my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is matching `className` with a regexp. But it's not very elegant:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
  // surround with spaces so that each class name can be matched with spaces
  var match = / index(\d+) /g.exec(" " + this.className + " ");
  var index = match[1];
});
```

---

`className` is a space-separated string of classes that the element has:

```
"foo"
"foo bar"
```

By surrounding with spaces, they become:

```
" foo "
" foo bar "
```

Note that with the surrounding spaces, each class name can be matched against `" foo "` with the correct result.

Comment: Would this work if there are no spaces before and after the class name in the markup?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: Yes, precisely because they're prepended/appended in this code (so `"index1"` will become `" index1 "` before matching, so that it works).

Comment: +1 perhaps you could combine with roxons answer below and apply this function only to: `tr[class^=index]`

Comment: @cowls: But that will only select rows that have index as the first item in the class list.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: It's basically just the `class` attribute from HTML. But if you use `.addClass` etc, then `className` gets updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

use the `*=` that will match for "contains" the specific word

`$('tr[class*=index]')`

and to retrieve the Number ( `[0]` if index is the first class!):

```
var classIndex = this.className.split(' ')[0].split('index')[1];
```

http://jsbin.com/awacet/1/edit

**OR if you are sure no other NUMBERS are in the classes but that one, than it's really simple:**

```
 var classIndex = this.className.replace(/\D/g, '' );
```

if you have e.g: `<tr class="something index4 footer barbeque"></tr>` this will return `4`

http://jsbin.com/awacet/2/edit

Comment: You probably would want `*=` in case the class is not the first one, example: http://jsfiddle.net/swE7b/

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure this addresses the issue. I already have the row. I want to get the value of *N* for that row. How would this help me?

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.class-1')[0].className.indexOf('class-') !== -1
```

Comment: I have no idea what this does, or how it would help in this task.

Comment: @arhea this code only tests whether the element has a class starting with class-  .. it doesnt get the row number that the OP is asking for